# Order Request UseCase

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, infopath, form

Please can someone provide me with some ideas or hints to solve the following issue?

Order List:

Column:     a   b   c   d   e   f   g

User: Order processor, customer

To create a new Order, a customer should add a new item in the Order List. The customer should only see and be able to edit the columns from a-d. The order processor then edits the item and adds the columns from e-g. The order processor should see all the items and columns of the list.

The customer should only see his items and only the columns from a-d.
Is there a way to implement this use case in a list maybe with different views?

Or is it better to create two lists with different permissions one for the customer and one for the order processor.  If I have to implement it in two lists what are the best way to be sure that the information entered by the customer is passed to the order processor and stored in his list? (maybe with a WorkFlow)?

Or is there a complete different way to implement this use case.
I´m on a SharePoint 2010 farm, InfoPath ad SPD can be used if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, permissions and access in SharePoint is configured in 3 levels OOTB: Web, List and List Items. So there is no way of setting permissions on list fields or views OOTB. Unless you want to use a 3rd party application, I would say go for 2 lists.

In the 2 lists solution, just create columns a-d on list1 and e-g on list2 + a lookup field to list1 so items in list2 can be connected to items in list1. list1 data entry is just normal OOTB SharePoint. But for list2 change the new form to an IF form, move the drop down lookup on list1 to the top so the Order Processor can choose an item from list1 first, which populates some read-only fields (a-d fields) on the form. Then go on with filling e-g fields on the IF form. So basically the IF form is the same as original except a section at the top which loads some read-only fields when list1 item is selected from drop down. Now for permissions, simply grant permission to customers on list1 and for Order Processors, grant permission on list2 (and also list1 if you want to).

You may also consider, for later reporting purposes, to store a-d fields also on list2 (duplicate). This way you can guarantee that every future requirements can be met, of course at the cost of saving duplicate data. Well this trade-off is always the case about SharePoint.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I´m going to implement the solution in two lists. In the first list a user can place an order request. After submission I will remove the contribute rights from this specific list item. The order processor then needs to create a new entry in the second list as you suggested.

Comment: Exactly. For the first list which is populated by customer, if you want the customers to be able to just add records and NOT to edit their orders (which makes sense), you can define a new permission level in site settings "Item Creator" which is the same as contributor with the difference that they CANNOT "Update List Items" or "Delete List Items". Grant the customers "Item Creator" permission on orders list. For more information about permission levels refer to: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx

Comment: I thought of implementing a WF to replace permission, but creating a "Item Creator"-permission level is a better choice... if the customer want to edit his request, I would let him do so but I will keep all the versions.